# how to input API info to react-plotly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, plotly, node-modules, plotly.js

I looked through the docs and couldn't find where the API username and key should go in the React component.

I have this for node:

```
const plotly = require('plotly')('username', 'API key')
```

what would the equivalent code be for React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly.js is a stand alone library and doesn't use the streaming and REST APIs of the nodejs version of Plotly. It generates the graphs through d3 on the client. So, no credentials are necessary.